# req undefined when error checking in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, servlets, request, error-checking

I am using Node.js to do error checking on the request from the UI. The UI has 3 input fields- size, color, and style. A user must select color and size but does not have to select style. So the error checking should make sure that they select color and size.

```
if (req.query.size == 'undefined' || req.query.color == 'undefined') {
    console.log("Did not select size or color");
    res.json({
        Error: "Must pick size and color!"
    });
} else {
    console.log(req.query.color);
    console.log(req.query.size);
    var selection = 'api' + req.query.size + '/' + req.query.color;
};
```

When the user does not select color and size, it does not catch this and instead goes to the 'else'. In which case, the console prints 'undefined' for color and size. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Note that if I do

```
req.query.size == undefined || req.query.color == undefined
```

or

```
typeof req.query.size == 'undefined' || typeof req.query.color == 'undefined'
```

I get an error in the console saying "Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object." I noticed that in index.js, which came with the Node Modules, there is the following code:

```
function request (uri, options, callback) {
   if (typeof uri === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')
   }
   ....
   return new request.Request(params)
}
```

Should I just take this out completely?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is on the client. If the user does not select size or color they are undefined in the request rather than 'N/A'. You could check for undefined as well in your first if statement

```
if (req.query.size === 'N/A' || req.query.size === undefined ...
```

Comment: thank you, my question was not clear, I updated it. When I tried to do req.query.size == undefined as you suggested, I get this error in the console: "Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object."

Comment: Try typeof req.query.size == 'undefined'

Comment: thanks but this works the same as if I do req.query.size === undefined. I get the correct output but the console has error: "Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object"

Comment: just realized that in index.js in Node modules, it has "if (typeof uri === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')
  }", this was preset. Maybe I should just take it out?